# Effects of ip options drop command on Cisco 4507 Device

Tags: cisco, ip, security, troubleshooting

Are there any services or applications traversing a router that will be impacted by the command, "ip options drop"? I know the router warns about RSVP when you input this command, but this 4510 is not running MPLS or MPLS Traffic Engineering.  The command is new to my environment.  The only issue I am seeing on the device is that a show ip traffic shows a bunch of encapsulation failed messages.